# sql error :SQLSTATE[HY093] while binding params

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hi is use this pdo php class 
https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class

i use it for connecting to db and crud until now all jobs works fine

but when i run this code keep getting this error :SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

all of binds works fine except this :

```
    function generateRandomString()
{
    $length = 5;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $key = $randomString;
    $setto = false;
    while ($setto == false) {
                $result = $this->db->query('SELECT `vkey` FROM `polls` WHERE `vkey`=:vkey', array(
                    'vkey' => $key
                ));
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
            }
            $key = $randomString;
        } else {
            $setto = true;
        }
    }
    echo $key;
    return $key;
}
```

i try to get a random stirng and check it in db before it use that code or not .

here is my complete code `
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

```
function addpoll($args, $questions)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2 + $questions; $i ++) {
        $args[$i] = parent::escape($args[$i]);
    }
    $args[1] = parent::convertHashtags($args[1]);
    $this->db->bind('title', $args[0]);
    $this->db->bind('description', $args[1]);
    $this->db->bind('answer1', $args[2]);
    $this->db->bind('answer2', $args[2]);
    $param = '';
    if ($questions > 2) {
        for ($i = 3; $i < $questions + 1; $i ++) {
            $param = $param . ':answer' . $i . ',';
            $this->db->bind('answer' . $i, $args[$i]);
        }
        if (10 - $questions > 0) {
            $count = 0;
            while (10 - $questions > $count) {
                $param = $param . ' \'\' ,';
                $count ++;
            }
        }
    } else {

        $count = 0;
        while (10 - $questions > $count) {

            $param = $param . ' \'\' ,';
            $count ++;
        }
    }

    $this->db->bind('subject', $args[$questions + 1]);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`, `title`, `about`, `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`, `answer6`, `answer7`, `answer8`, `answer9`, `answer10`, `mode`, `confirmation`, `who`, `password`, `confirmed`, `createdate`, `expiredate`,`subject`,`pkey`) VALUES (NULL,:title, :description ,:answer1 ,:answer2,';
    $param = $param . ' 0 , 0 , 0 , \'\' , 0 ,' . time() . ' ,';

    $settings = time() + ($args[$questions + 3] * 86400) . ',:subject , ';
    $sql = $sql . $param . $settings . '\'' . $this->generateRandomString() . '\'' . ')';
    echo $sql;

    $this->db->query($sql);
}

private function getsub($id)
{
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE id=:sid ', array(
        'sid' => $id
    ));
    if (count($result) == 1) {
        return $id;
    }

    return 1;
}

function generateRandomString()
{
    $length = 5;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $key = $randomString;
    $setto = false;
    while ($setto == false) {
                $result = $this->db->query('SELECT `vkey` FROM `polls` WHERE `id`=:id', array(
                    'id' => $key
                ));
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
            }
            $key = $randomString;
        } else {
            $setto = true;
        }
    }
    echo $key;
    return $key;
}
```

`
i tried diffrent keywords like :vkey2 or.. and echo all of variables 
thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's this query that cause that error?
The error meaning is the amount of the parameters isn't equal to the amount of the placeholders.
BTW, I hope that the `echo $key` is just for debugging purpose.

Comment: yeah i sure . i echo all of variables everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the problem 
problem was in binds if you use this class dont ever try bind variables before the execute just store them in array and ate the end bind with execute i change the code and work good ;)

```
private $binds=array();
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function addpoll($args, $questions)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2 + $questions; $i ++) {
        $args[$i] = parent::escape($args[$i]);
    }
    $args[1] = parent::convertHashtags($args[1]);

    $this->binds['title']=$args[0];
    $this->binds['description']=$args[1];
    $this->binds['answer1']=$args[2];
    $this->binds['answer2']=$args[3];
    $param = '';
    if ($questions > 2) {
        for ($i = 3; $i < $questions + 1; $i ++) {
            $param = $param . ':answer' . $i . ',';
            $this->binds['answer' . $i]= $args[$i];
        }
        if (10 - $questions > 0) {
            $count = 0;
            while (10 - $questions > $count) {
                $param = $param . ' \'\' ,';
                $count ++;
            }
        }
    } else {

        $count = 0;
        while (10 - $questions > $count) {

            $param = $param . ' \'\' ,';
            $count ++;
        }
    }
    $this->binds['subject']=$args[$questions + 1];
    $this->binds['date']=time();
    $this->binds['todate']=time() + ($args[$questions + 3] * 86400);
    $this->binds['pkey']=$this->generateRandomString();


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`, `title`, `about`, `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`, `answer6`, `answer7`, `answer8`, `answer9`, `answer10`, `mode`, `confirmation`, `who`, `password`, `confirmed`, `createdate`, `expiredate`,`subject`,`pkey`) VALUES (NULL,:title, :description ,:answer1 ,:answer2,';
    $param = $param . ' 0 , 0 , 0 , \'\' , 0 ,:date ,';
    echo 'test';
    $settings = ':todate ,:subject , ';
    $sql = $sql . $param . $settings . ':pkey)';

    $this->db->query($sql,$this->binds);
}

private function getsub($id)
{
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE id=:sid ', array(
        'sid' => $id
    ));
    if (count($result) == 1) {
        return $id;
    }

    return 1;
}

function generateRandomString()
{
    $length = 5;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $key = $randomString;
    $setto = false;
    while ($setto == false) {
                $result =  $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `polls` WHERE pkey=:pkey ', array(
        'pkey' => $key
    ));
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
            }
            $key = $randomString;
        } else {
            $setto = true;
        }
    }

    return $key;
}
```